# Connotation of question "marked as duplicate"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, upvotes

If a question is "marked as duplicate", is it considered good or bad in the eyes of the community?

I've seen questions being "marked as duplicate" but have multiple upvotes and are even favorited multiple times as well

(Example question: [Difference between onCreate() and onStart()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812003/difference-between-oncreate-and-onstart?rq=1))

So if a question is marked as a duplicate, does it necessarily follow that it's a good/bad question?

Comment: If Google search or organic browsing leads me to a duplicate that in turn leads me to an answer, I'll upvote the duplicate, especially if the target question isn't great.  (Trying to get the questions merged or the duplication direction reversed is usually more effort than it's worth.)

Comment: It's usually a badly researched question. The quality of the post has nothing to do with the duplicate mark.

Comment: There's no shame, or penalty, in posting a question that's closed as a dupe. Downvotes are what can hurt you in the long run. I only downvote if it's obvious the asker did no research

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> So if a question is marked as a duplicate, does it necessarily follow that it's a good/bad question?

<strike>Depends</strike> No.

Sometimes the duplicate is 100% duplicate, in both wording and causes. In this case, the question doesn't have any added value and there is no reason to upvote it.

In other cases, at first glance, it's hard to see that the question is a duplicate, but if you dig deep enough, you can see that the causes are the same, and the original solution fits in this case as well. These questions can be very helpful as they introduce the same problem from different angles, so they are worth upvoting and keeping in mind.

Comment: It can be surprisingly hard to convince a poster that it [indeed is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22not+a+duplicate%22), even though they usually don't have to dig very deep...

Comment: I think it comes with the 'stigma' of a question being marked as duplicate. As stated by Maroun Maroun earlier, questions marked as duplicate is not necessarily a bad thing. I'd like to think that these 'good' duplicates make the problem more visible to everyone, and consequentially, its solutions

Comment: s/Depends/No/ – as in »No, it does *not* automatically follow«.

Comment: @IngoBürk Depends.

Comment: Questions are also considered dupe-closable if they are different (within reason) but have the same answer, according to the guidance usage for the Mjolnir dupehammer.

Comment: Whenever I ask a question that is marked duplicate it is slightly insulting. I alway put some effort into figuring out my issue with no luck and usually run across whatever is being touted as the "original". All I see is some jackass with several thousand rep copping out of helping without actually being of any service (I know they don't owe me any service, but they could just ignore the question and let someone else help instead of closing the question). Granted there are users that do post without doing any research, but it still strikes me as a brush off.

Comment: Whenever I see a comment referring to a duplicate close-voter as a jackass copping out of helping, it is slightly insulting.

Comment: @tbirrell: If a close-voter couldn't tell from the details of what's posted that it wasn't a duplicate, whose fault was it? (Hint: "I totally searched around a bunch and found absolutely nothing" is an extremely common and absolutely meaningless sentiment that is often belied by a quite obvious duplicate found within 15 minutes.) And in the majority of cases, when it *is* a duplicate, someone taking the trouble to give an answer (usually) without possibility of reward for their time is not only performing a service for the community in keeping questions organized, but for the asker as well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Granted. The vast majority of the time, the duplicate does not solve the problem. This does not stop the closer, despite most of my best efforts to show otherwise. I recognize there are valid reasons for the system as is, I'm just sharing my POV.

Comment: @tbirrell: I have to admit I feel considerable skepticism toward "the vast majority of the time". Many askers voluntarily confirm duplicate closure; many more make no attempt to dispute it, and I myself have had questions on various sites closed as duplicates, and generally they actually were.

Comment: @LastManStanding The stigma comes from the fact that the majority of duplicates result from a lack of research. Actual good duplicates are much rarer.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I think tbirrel's talking about his personal experience, not the site-wide stats.  And I think it's true that a well-researched question closed as a duplicate is more likely to have been closed inappropriately than a badly-researched one, so he may well have an experience that doesn't match the average.

Answer (score 21):

A question being a marked duplicate is neither good nor bad, it's just a fact.

It can be good if it's a good sign-post, and it's bad if it isn't. A good sign-post makes the master easier to find by using different wording or even a different approach.

Usefulness is dominated by that, but other considerations still apply.

Comment: In many cases we need to ask why the original question is not being found..

Answer (score 15):

Worth reading: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

> One thing I want to be clear about, though, is that **duplication is not
> necessarily bad**. Quite the contrary -- some duplication is *desirable*.
> There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question
> around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different
> words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find
> the answer they’re looking for.

**Benefit**: you can find the same answer using different keywords to search.

> Let me be clear -- too much question duplication is bad. Absolutely.
> You'll get no argument whatsoever from me on that. But not enough
> question duplication is *also bad*.
>
> (...)
>
> So, as always, use your good judgment and please continue to close and merge duplicates as you see fit. However, bear in mind that cultivating and supporting a moderate amount of natural duplication actively helps the community.

So, if the question is a good duplicate that helped you or may help others, upvote it!

Answer (score 10):

Duplicate questions *can* be bad questions, but not always. Quoting [MSE FAQ 'How should duplicate questions be handled?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> #### Should I downvote?
>
> It depends. Duplicate questions are not necessarily bad; different
>   descriptions of the same problem help future visitors to find the
>   answers they're looking for.  However, asking a duplicate question may
>   indicate a lack of adequate preparation prior to asking, which is
>   always grounds for downvoting.

The primary goal of closing questions as duplicates is to avoid fragmentation of answers. Judging questions on their quality comes second.

A question that appears to be a very obvious duplicate, can be considered a bad question because the asker appears to not have taken the effort to research their problem.
Other questions that appear to be duplicates should be judged as if they weren't: still vote to close them, but also up- or downvote (or don't vote at all) based on the question quality.

Questions can also gather a bunch of upvotes before it is noticed that it's a duplicate question. Two independent questions could both gather for example 30 upvotes in a year, without anyone knowing that they're duplicates of eachother.